# Need Query to Group Tree Hierarchy Items

Tags: mysql

I have a MYsql table `indexlistapp` that looks like this:

```
  Index     Seq    Tree     App                                 Idx  
| 791525 | 139 |    1  |    1.8L (turbo gas)                 |  .NULL.  
| 791525 | 140 |    2  |    VIN C (5th digit, engine ID AWD  |  300-76318B  
| 791525 | 141 |    2  |    VIN D (5th digit, engine ID AWW) |  300-67718B  
| 791525 | 142 |    1  |    1.9L (turbo diesel)              |  .NULL.  
| 791525 | 143 |    2  |    VIN F (5th digit)                |  .NULL.  
| 791525 | 144 |    3  |    MT                               |  300-76119A  
| 791525 | 145 |    3  |    AT                               |  300-76119B  
| 791525 | 146 |    2  |    VIN P (5th digit)                |  .NULL.  
| 791525 | 147 |    3  |    MT                               |  300-76119A  
| 791525 | 148 |    3  |    AT                               |  300-76119B  
| 791525 | 149 |    1  |    2.0L (gasoline)                  |  .NULL.  
| 791525 | 150 |    2  |    VIN S (5th digit, engine ID AEG) |  300-76120  
| 791525 | 151 |    2  |    VIN T (5th digit, engine ID AEG) |  300-76120  
| 791525 | 152 |    2  |    VIN B (5th digit)                |  300-67995  
| 791525 | 153 |    2  |    VIN K (5th digit)                |  300-67995  
| 791525 | 154 |    1  |    2.8L (VIN G, 5th digit)          |  300-67328B
```

The records with a value in the Idx column represent a completed "node" or sequence, if you will.

I'd like to output the data with a query so that the data is displayed with each option represented as one line as below:

```
  App                                                        Idx
| 1.9L (turbo diesel), VIN F (5th digit), AT              |  300-76119B         
| 1.9L (turbo diesel), VIN F (5th digit), MT              |  300-76119A  
| 1.9L (turbo diesel), VIN P (5th digit), AT              |  300-76119B  
| 1.9L (turbo diesel), VIN P (5th digit), MT              |  300-76119A  
| 1.8L (turbo gas), VIN C (5th digit, engine ID AWD)      |  300-76318B  
| 1.8L (turbo gas), VIN D (5th digit, engine ID AWW)      |  300-67718B  
| 2.0L (gasoline), VIN S (5th digit, engine ID AEG)       |  300-76120  
| 2.0L (gasoline), VIN T (5th digit, engine ID AEG)       |  300-76120  
| 2.8L (VIN G, 5th digit)                                 |  300-67328B  
| 2.0L (gasoline), VIN B (5th digit)                      |  300-67995  
| 2.0L (gasoline), VIN K (5th digit)                      |  300-67995
```

The app description and idx value represents a unique item, in this case this list shows all the available specific engine types for a 2001 Volkswagen Jetta.

Comment: Please post the input output with the code you have tried in text form, using proper formatting.

Comment: Updated. As I mention in my post I don't even know where to start with a query. I've converted the table with a variety of queries and cursor scans but I suspect the right query would do the job.

Comment: Good work with the edit!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get some help with this query and function..solved.

```
SELECT get_path(seqnbr, treelevel,indexlistid) app, InterchangeNumber FROM 
Indexlistapp WHERE InterchangeNumber is not null and indexlistid = 791525 order by 
app asc


FUNCTION get_path(_seqnbr,_treelevel,_indexlistid)
BEGIN
DECLARE _parentseqnbr decimal(6,0);   
DECLARE _application TEXT;

SET @ret = '';    

-- Loop until the _treelevel is 0
WHILE _treelevel > 0 DO
    -- Select the record at the _treelevel the is <= seqnbr
    SELECT seqnbr, application
    INTO _parentseqnbr, _application
    FROM indexlistapp
    WHERE seqnbr <= _seqnbr AND treelevel = _treelevel and indexlistid = _indexlistid
    ORDER BY seqnbr DESC
    LIMIT 1;        

    -- Concatenate the application field with the previous values in the loop        
    SET @ret := CONCAT(_application, ', ', @ret);

    -- Set the values for the next iteration of the loop
    SET _seqnbr := _parentseqnbr;
    SET _treelevel := _treelevel - 1;    

end WHILE;

-- Remove the extra ', ' from the end of the string
RETURN TRIM(TRAILING ', ' FROM @ret);
```

END

Answer (score 0):

I do it using oracle11g sql single statement as follow:

```
select decode(instr(apps, '/', 2), 0, substr(apps, 2), 
substr(apps, 2, instr(apps, '/', 2)-2)||', '||substr(apps, instr(apps, '/', 2)+1)),  idx 
from (
select sys_connect_by_path(app, '/') as apps, idx
from (
select x.*, 
(case when tree = 1 then ROW_NUMBER else ceil(ROW_NUMBER/tree) end) lvl, 
min(seq) OVER (partition by (case when tree = 1 then ROW_NUMBER else ceil(ROW_NUMBER/tree) end)) AS parent_tree
from (
select a.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by tree order by seq) as ROW_NUMBER
FROM INDEXLISTAPP a
) x
)
where idx is not null
start with seq = parent_tree 
connect by NOCYCLE PRIOR seq = parent_tree
order by apps
)
;
```

Comment: I've tried to convert this to Mysql using an online converter to start, but not surprised it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi @ahmed-elabed, I tested this query in Oracle and it is close, but it's duplicating some rows and not including certain elements in each row.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04b48f/7/0

Answer (score 0):

I start to solve it using mysql 5.7 as follow:

```
set @pk1 ='';
set @rn1 =1;
SELECT  tree, seq, App, indx, rowNumber
FROM
(
SELECT  tree, seq, app, indexlistapp.Index as indx, 
@rn1 := if(@pk1=tree, @rn1+1,tree) as rowNumber, 
@pk1 := tree
FROM    indexlistapp
    ORDER BY seq
) A ;
```

I will copmlete it next time, so i am busy now,

thank you

Comment: Thank you, so far so good. I see now that there is a new field, rowNumber that I suppose is going to be used in some additional subquery.

Comment: Hi @ahmed don't mean to rush you but I was curious if you had anything further on this Mysql query.